# readonly class design when a non-readonly class is already in place

Tags: c#, readonly

I have a class that upon construction, loads it's info from a database.  The info is all modifiable, and then the developer can call Save() on it to make it Save that information back to the database.

I am also creating a class that will load from the database, but won't allow any updates to it. (a read only version.)  My question is, should I make a separate class and inherit, or should I just update the existing object to take a readonly parameter in the constructor, or should I make a separate class entirely?

The existing class is already used in many places in the code.

Thanks.

**Update:**

Firstly, there's a lot of great answers here.  It would be hard to accept just one. Thanks everyone.

**The main problems it seems are:**

- Meeting expectations based on class names and inheritance structures.
- Preventing unnecessary duplicate code

There seems to be a big difference between Readable and ReadOnly.  A Readonly class should probably not be inherited.  But a Readable class suggests that it might also gain writeability at some point.

So after much thought, here's what I'm thinking:

```
public class PersonTestClass
{
    public static void Test()
    {

        ModifiablePerson mp = new ModifiablePerson();
        mp.SetName("value");
        ReadOnlyPerson rop = new ReadOnlyPerson();
        rop.GetName();
        //ReadOnlyPerson ropFmp = (ReadOnlyPerson)mp;  // not allowed.
        ReadOnlyPerson ropFmp = (ReadOnlyPerson)(ReadablePerson)mp; 
          // above is allowed at compile time (bad), not at runtime (good).
        ReadablePerson rp = mp;
    }
}

public class ReadablePerson
{
    protected string name;
    public string GetName()
    {
        return name;
    }        
}
public sealed class ReadOnlyPerson : ReadablePerson
{
}
public class ModifiablePerson : ReadablePerson
{
    public void SetName(string value)
    {
        name = value;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't yet know how to do this with properties (see StriplingWarrior's answer for this done with properties), but I have a feeling it will involve the protected keyword and [asymmetric property access modifiers](http://newoldthing.wordpress.com/2007/09/02/c-property-access-modifier/).

Also, fortunately for me, the data that is loaded from the database does not have to be turned into reference objects, rather they are simple types.  This means I don't really have to worry about people modifying the members of the `ReadOnlyPerson` object.

**Update 2:**

Note, as StriplingWarrior has suggested, downcasting can lead to problems, but this is generally true as casting a Monkey to and Animal back down to a Dog can be bad.  However, it seems that even though the casting is allowed at compile time, it is not actually allowed at runtime.

A wrapper class may also do the trick, but I like this better because it avoids the problem of having to deep copy the passed in object / allow the passed in object to be modified thus modifying the wrapper class.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) says that you shouldn't make your read-only class inherit from your read-write class, because consuming classes would have to be aware that they can't call the Save method on it without getting an exception.

Making the writable class extend the readable class would make more sense to me, as long as there is nothing on the readable class that indicates its object can never be persisted. For example, I wouldn't call the base class a `ReadOnly[Whatever]`, because if you have a method that takes a `ReadOnlyPerson` as an argument, that method would be justified in assuming that it would be impossible for anything they do to that object to have any impact on the database, which is not necessarily true if the actual instance is a `WriteablePerson`.

#### Update

I was originally assuming that in your read-only class you only wanted to prevent people calling the `Save` method. Based on what I'm seeing in your answer-response to your question (which should actually be an update on your question, by the way), here's a pattern you might want to follow:

```
public abstract class ReadablePerson
{

    public ReadablePerson(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; protected set; }

}

public sealed class ReadOnlyPerson : ReadablePerson
{
    public ReadOnlyPerson(string name) : base(name)
    {
    }
}

public sealed class ModifiablePerson : ReadablePerson
{
    public ModifiablePerson(string name) : base(name)
    {
    }
    public new string Name { 
        get {return base.Name;}
        set {base.Name = value; }
    }
}
```

This ensures that a truly `ReadOnlyPerson` cannot simply be cast as a ModifiablePerson and modified. If you're willing to trust that developers won't try to down-cast arguments in this way, though, I prefer the interface-based approach in Steve and Olivier's answers.

Another option would be to make your `ReadOnlyPerson` just be a wrapper class for a `Person` object. This would necessitate more boilerplate code, but it comes in handy when you can't change the base class.

One last point, since you enjoyed learning about the Liskov Substitution Principle: By having the Person class be responsible for loading itself out of the database, you are breaking the Single-Responsibility Principle. Ideally, your Person class would have properties to represent the data that comprises a "Person," and there would be a different class (maybe a `PersonRepository`) that's responsible for producing a Person from the database or saving a Person to the database.

#### Update 2

Responding to your comments:

- While you can technically answer your own question, StackOverflow is largely about getting answers from other people. That's why it won't let you accept your own answer until a certain grace period has passed. You are encouraged to refine your question and respond to comments and answers until someone has come up with an adequate solution to your initial question.
- I made the `ReadablePerson` class `abstract` because it seemed like you'd only ever want to create a person that is read-only or one that is writeable. Even though both of the child classes could be considered to be a ReadablePerson, what would be the point of creating a `new ReadablePerson()` when you could just as easily create a `new ReadOnlyPerson()`? Making the class abstract requires the user to choose one of the two child classes when instantiating them.
- A PersonRepository would sort of be like a factory, but the word "repository" indicates that you're actually pulling the person's information from some data source, rather than creating the person out of thin air.
- In my mind, the Person class would just be a POCO, with no logic in it: just properties. The repository would be responsible for building the Person object. Rather than saying:

  ```
  // This is what I think you had in mind originally
  var p = new Person(personId);
  ```

  ... and allowing the Person object to go to the database to populate its various properties, you would say:

  ```
  // This is a better separation of concerns
  var p = _personRepository.GetById(personId);
  ```

  The PersonRepository would then get the appropriate information out of the database and construct the Person with that data.

  If you wanted to call a method that has no reason to change the person, you could protect that person from changes by converting it to a Readonly wrapper (following the pattern that the .NET libraries follow with the `ReadonlyCollection<T>` class). On the other hand, methods that require a writeable object could be given the `Person` directly:

  ```
  var person = _personRepository.GetById(personId);
  // Prevent GetVoteCount from changing any of the person's information
  int currentVoteCount = GetVoteCount(person.AsReadOnly()); 
  // This is allowed to modify the person. If it does, save the changes.
  if(UpdatePersonDataFromLdap(person))
  {
       _personRepository.Save(person);
  }
  ```
- The benefit of using interfaces is that you're not forcing a specific class hierarchy. This will give you better flexibility in the future. For example, let's say that for the moment you write your methods like this:

  ```
  GetVoteCount(ReadablePerson p);
  UpdatePersonDataFromLdap(ReadWritePerson p);
  ```

  ... but then in two years you decide to change to the wrapper implementation. Suddenly `ReadOnlyPerson` is no longer a `ReadablePerson`, because it's a wrapper class instead of an extension of a base class. Do you change `ReadablePerson` to `ReadOnlyPerson` in all your method signatures?

  Or say you decide to simplify things and just consolidate all your classes into a single `Person` class: now you have to change all your methods to just take Person objects. On the other hand, if you had programmed to interfaces:

  ```
  GetVoteCount(IReadablePerson p);
  UpdatePersonDataFromLdap(IReadWritePerson p);
  ```

  ... then these methods don't care what your object hierarchy looks like, as long as the objects you give them implement the interfaces they ask for. You can change your implementation hierarchy at any time without having to change these methods at all.

Comment: ah, very cool. +1 for introducing a new principle to me.  So I might call the first class ReadablePerson and the inherited one ReadableWritablePerson.

Comment: @user420667: I'd prefer `ReadWritePerson`, `ModifiablePerson`, or even just `Person`. I also updated my answer with some more pointers. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Nice update.  I may use the wrapper idea.  Blasted downcasting.  Not sure why I'm not supposed to answer my own questions if I came up with what I thought was a better solution.  Also, why did you make the ReadablePerson class abstract?  Also, a PersonRepository would be like a Person factory?  I'm not really sure how that would fit with the notion of a ReadOnlyPerson.  You would have to pass the PersonRepository to the Person constructor, wouldn't you?

Comment: also, could you explain what is preferable about the interface approach?

Comment: @user420667: I updated my answer to respond to your questions.

Comment: thanks for the detailed responses.  I will have to think about them a bit.

Comment: I think the discussion has gotten a bit off-topic, although I've enjoyed it and think it touches on some of the big topics in design.  The only qualm I have with the wrapper idea is that it allows me to change the object I passed in to be wrapped, that or it requires a deep copy of the object. This means I prefer my/our approach to msdn's :-P.  I also like the respository idea, as it provides good layering and it doesn't make sense to call Person.Save().  Perhaps one could even have an interface IObjectRepository.

Comment: But I still don't see the interfaces as being a *better* option, although they are an option.  1) Even if i changed the ReadonlyPerson to be a wrapper, I wouldn't change the derived nature of it.  2) Wouldn't the arguments apply just as easily if I wanted to consolidate/change the interface structure?  I feel that maybe this discussion belongs elsewhere, perhaps chat / a separate question / email.  I think it's a good one though.

Comment: @user420667: A Wrapper class does neither of the things you're claiming it does. All it does is keep a private handle on the original object and expose *only* the methods you want it to. It uses pass-through calls to the original object for those methods that it does expose. Use ILSpy to look at how ReadOnlyCollection is implemented.

Comment: If the object you pass is modified, then the wrapper (which in this case was supposed to be readonly) is modified.  That is unless you make a constructor which passes all the fields (basically a deep copy) or have your constructor which takes the object to be wrapped do the deep copy itself.

Comment: @user420667: I guess it depends on what you're trying to prevent. If you want the method to be able to assume that the Person object cannot be changed in another thread while it's running, then you're right. If you just want the calling method to know ensure that a method won't mess with the Person object when its contract said it was only planning to *read* the Person, then a wrapper class would be sufficient.

Answer (score 6):

Definitely do not make the read-only class inherit from the writable class. Derived classes should extend and modify the capabilities of the base class; they should never take capabilities away.

You may be able to make the writable class inherit from the read-only class, but you need to do it carefully. The key question to ask is, would any consumers of the read-only class rely on the fact that it is read-only? If a consumer is counting on the values never changing, but the writable derived type is passed in and then the values are changed, that consumer could be broken.

I know it is tempting to think that because the structure of the two types (i.e. the data that they contain) is similar or identical, that one should inherit from the other. But that is often not the case. If they are being designed for significantly different use cases, they probably need to be separate classes.

Comment: Thanks for the gedanken experiment.  Perhaps that just means I should override the implicit and explicit casting operators to prevent the cast?  But then that sort of defeats the purpose of inheritance, doesn't it?  Darn.  There must be a better way.

Comment: You can't override cast operators for types in the same hierarchy (and even if you could it would be a terrible idea). A type can always be impilcitly converted to its base type.

Comment: Darn, that is a very fair and annoying concern.

Comment: I would posit that the proper approach would be to have an abstract "readable" class (or interface), which could then have both writable and immutable derived classes (or interfaces).  While some users of an collection class may rely upon its being immutable, and others may rely upon its being immutable, an awful lot aren't going to care one way or the other provided they can read it.  There's no reason methods that don't care whether a class is mutable shouldn't be able to operate the same way on mutable and immutable ones.

Answer (score 6):

A quick option might be to create an `IReadablePerson` (etc) interface, which contains only get properties, and does not include Save().  Then you can have your existing class implement that interface, and where you need Read-only access, have the consuming code reference the class through that interface.

In keeping with the pattern, you probably want to have a `IReadWritePerson` interface, as well, which would contain the setters and `Save()`.

**Edit** On further thought, `IWriteablePerson` should probably be `IReadWritePerson`, since it wouldn't make much sense to have a write-only class.

Example:

```
public interface IReadablePerson
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public interface IReadWritePerson : IReadablePerson
{
    new string Name { get; set; }
    void Save();
}

public class Person : IReadWritePerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public void Save() {}
}
```

Comment: +1 for me liking that idea.  But it is easy to make such an interface with properties?  Like one could have Name { get;} and the other Name {set; } ?

Comment: Absolutely.  See the example I added, or see also @Olivier Jacot-Descombes' answer.

Answer (score 5):

The question is, "how do you want to turn a modifiable class into a read-only class by inheriting from it?"
With inheritance you can extend a class but not restrict it. Doing so by throwing exceptions would violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (LSP).

The other way round, namely deriving a modifiable class from a read-only class would be OK from this point of view; however, how do you want to turn a read-only property into a read-write property? And, moreover, is it desirable to be able to substitute a modifiable object where a read-only object is expected?

However, you can do this with interfaces

```
interface IReadOnly
{
    int MyProperty { get; }
}

interface IModifiable : IReadOnly
{
    new int MyProperty { set; }
    void Save();
}
```

This class is assignment compatible to the `IReadOnly` interface as well. In read-only contexts you can access it through the `IReadOnly` interface.

```
class ModifiableClass : IModifiable
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public void Save()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE

I did some further investigations on the subject.

However, there is a caveat to this, I had to add a `new` keyword in `IModifiable` and you can only access the getter either directly through the `ModifiableClass` or through the `IReadOnly` interface, but not through the `IModifiable` interface.

I also tried to work with two interfaces `IReadOnly` and `IWriteOnly` having only a getter or a setter respectively. You can then declare an interface inheriting from both of them and no `new` keyword is required in front of the property (as in `IModifiable`).  However when you try to access the property of such an object you get the compiler error `Ambiguity between 'IReadOnly.MyProperty' and 'IWriteOnly.MyProperty'`.

Obviously, it is not possible to synthesize a property from separate getters and setters, as I expected.

Comment: No need to implement two separate classes, as long as you use the IReadOnly interface when you want to use the class in a read-only context.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem to solve when creating an object for user security permissions, that in certain cases must be mutable to allow high-level users to modify security settings, but normally is read-only to store the currently logged-in user's permissions information without allowing code to modify those permissions on the fly.

The pattern I came up with was to define an interface which the mutable object implements, that has read-only property getters. The mutable implementation of that interface can then be private, allowing code that directly deals with instantiating and hydrating the object to do so, but once the object is returned out of that code (as an instance of the interface) the setters are no longer accessible.

Example:

```
//this is what "ordinary" code uses for read-only access to user info.
public interface IUser
{
   string UserName {get;}
   IEnumerable<string> PermissionStrongNames {get;}

   ...
}

//This class is used for editing user information.
//It does not implement the interface, and so while editable it cannot be 
//easily used to "fake" an IUser for authorization
public sealed class EditableUser 
{
   public string UserName{get;set;}
   List<SecurityGroup> Groups {get;set;}

   ...
}

...

//this class is nested within the class responsible for login authentication,
//which returns instances as IUsers once successfully authenticated
private sealed class AuthUser:IUser
{
   private readonly EditableUser user;

   public AuthUser(EditableUser mutableUser) { user = mutableUser; }

   public string UserName {get{return user.UserName;}}

   public IEnumerable<string> PermissionNames 
   {
       //GetPermissions is an extension method that traverses the list of nestable Groups.
       get {return user.Groups.GetPermissions().Select(p=>p.StrongName);
   }

   ...
}
```

A pattern like this allows you to use code you've already created in a read-write fashion, while not allowing Joe Programmer to turn a read-only instance into a mutable one. There are a few more tricks in my actual implementation, mainly dealing with persistence of the editable object (since editing user records is a secured action, an EditableUser cannot be saved with the Repository's "normal" persistence method; it instead requires calling an overload that also takes an IUser which must have sufficient permissions).

One thing you simply must understand; if it is possible for your program to edit the records in any scope, it is possible for that ability to be abused, whether intentionally or otherwise. Regular code reviews of any usage of the mutable or immutable forms of your object will be necessary to make sure other coders aren't doing anything "clever". This pattern also isn't enough to ensure that an application used by the general public is secure; if you can write an IUser implementation, so can an attacker, so you'll need some additional way to verify that your code and not an attacker's produced a particular IUser instance, and that the instance hasn't been tampered with in the interim.

Comment: Interesting example.  However, what's stopping me from making an AuthUser with an editableuser, and then changing the editableuser's name, thus changing the authuser's name, which shouldn't be allowed given the intention of the IUser interface, right?

Comment: What's stopping you in this case is that you can't access AuthUser; it's a private nested class not accessible from outside the object that performs login authentication. Joe Programmer could still write his own IUser implementation, but if I'm the senior dev or architect  over Joe I could use ReSharper or a clever unit test to search the codebase for IUnit implementations I didn't authorize. If Joe was an attacker, I'd consider adding a hash value, generated by my (sealed and obfuscated) login authenticator, that could be used to quickly verify that my code did or didn't generate an IUser.

Comment: In any case I did say that the ability to go between mutable and immutable instances of an object must be closely monitored in any situation that could have security repercussions. Some of these other suggestions are no less vulnerable.